# remove character

Tags: javascript, string

i have a string like "|aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaa|"...now i just want to remove character "|" and replace them by "/n".

i tried these unsuccessfully:

```
function removeSeperator(str){
str = str.replace('|', "\n");
return str;}

function removeSeperator(str){
var rs="";
var i = 0;

for(i=0;i<str.trim().length;i++){
    if(str[i]=="|"){
        rs += str.substring(0, i) + "/n";
        str = str.substring(i+1);
    }
}

return rs;}
```

i have to do it on pure javascript, jquery is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

To replace multiple characters you'll need a regex with the global modifier :

```
var a = "|aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaa|";

var b = a.replace(/\|/g, "\n");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TQFM/1/)

As a callable function that would be:

```
function removeSeperator(str){
    return str.replace(/\|/g, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex to perform the replacement.

```
function removeSeperator(str){
    str = str.replace(/\|/g, "\n");
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the javascript replace method supports a singular value, for instance '|' will only replace the character once.  On the flip side you can use a regular expression such as "/\|/g", which will replace all occurrences of '|' with a new line.  In effect, your code would look something like this -

```
    function replaceString ( str ) {
        cleanedString = str.replace(/\|/g, "\n");
        return cleanedString;
    }
    var theString = "|aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaa|";

    window.alert(replaceString(theString));
```

The output will look something like -

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaa

Which in approximation, is what you're expecting.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a regular expression:

```
function removeSeperator(str){
    str = str.replace(/\|/g,'\n');
    return str;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b2vBw/1/)

simple replace only works for the first entry.
Also having 2 functions with the same name .. can make you some problems if this is your actual code.